# Items with absolute positioning create clutter in the flat list and hinder its functionality - react native

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

I have UI data that comes from the server, and I need to render it on the screen based on its width, height, x-axis, and y-axis.
I'm attempting to render this data using the absolute position, so I can manage the x and y axes.
However, it's not working correctly on Android.

Live Demo. [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/HQCLXM305?platform=android)

Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';

const dataFromServer = [
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 104,
    img_width: 419,
    img_height: 399,
    text: 'four',
  },

  {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    img_width: 424,
    img_height: 330,
    text: 'five',
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 57,
    img_width: 131,
    img_height: 205,
    text: 'one',
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 57,
    img_width: 136,
    img_height: 204,
    text: 'two',
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 57,
    img_width: 136,
    img_height: 204,
    text: 'three',
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 73,
    img_width: 419,
    img_height: 399,
    text: 'six',
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 26,
    img_width: 424,
    img_height: 399,
    text: 'seven',
  },
];
const maxWidth = 430;
//  Dimensions.get('window').width; // Maximum width of the canvas in pixels
const spacing = 5; // Optional spacing between items
console.log('maxWidth', maxWidth);
const App = () => {
  // Calculate grid positions for each item
  const calculateGridPositions = data => {
    let currentX = 0;
    let currentY = 0;
    const itemsWithPositions = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
      const {x, y, img_width, img_height, text} = item;
      const position = {left: currentX + x, top: currentY + y};
      currentX += img_width + spacing;

      // If the next item would exceed the maximum width, start a new row
      if (currentX + img_width > maxWidth) {
        currentX = 0;
        currentY += img_height + spacing;
      }

      itemsWithPositions.push({...item, position, text});
    });

    return itemsWithPositions;
  };

  const itemsWithPositions = calculateGridPositions(dataFromServer);

  // Render each item using the provided positions and dimensions
  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const {position, img_width, img_height, text} = item;

    const itemStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: position.left,
      top: position.top,
      width: img_width,
      height: img_height,
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    };

    return (
      <View style={[styles.gridItem, itemStyle]}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  // Calculate the total height of the screen
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

  // State to hold the total content height
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(screenHeight);

  // Calculate the content height and set it when the data changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const maxItemY = Math.max(
      ...itemsWithPositions.map(item => item.position.top + item.img_height),
    );
    const calculatedContentHeight = maxItemY + spacing;
    setContentHeight(calculatedContentHeight);
  }, [itemsWithPositions]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={itemsWithPositions}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#f00',
          height: contentHeight,
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  gridItem: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Am I missing something, or is it a bug in the Flatlist on Android?